# Post format selector in Thematic child theme post class

Tags: customization, child-theme, post-formats

I'm having a very hard time implementing post formats in my Thematic child theme. I am able to add post format theme support and add content via the big conditional statement, but the `.format-video`, etc. selectors do not appear in the post class so I can' use them to style the formats.

According to some echoing tests, the selector appears as it should in `post_class()` but is nowhere to be found in `thematic_post_class()`. 
I tried removing `thematic_post_class()` to let `post_class()` function instead:

```
// remove thematic_post_class to include post format selector in post class
function childtheme_override_post_class() {
     remove_action('thematic_post_class','thematic_access', 9);
}
add_action('init', 'childtheme_override_post_class');
```

With this function, `thematic_post_class()` no longer echoes, but the theme is still not registering the format selectors. I saw in another post that the `after_setup_theme` action hook worked to enable formats in a Twenty-Ten child - tried this in my theme but it made no difference:

```
function wpfolio_add_format_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery', 'video', 'link', 'image', 'quote') );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpfolio_add_format_support', 11);`
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `add_theme_support` looks like it should work. Is it just the `post_class` filter you need to get working?

Comment: Sorry - missed your reply somehow. Yeah, the format selectors show up in `post_class` but the theme won't read any style

Comment: What does "won't read any style" mean? I understood you got the `.format-$postformat` class added, so your problem is to the definition in your stylesheet is not read/processed?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If I override `thematic_post_class` the `.format-$postformat` class is there, but any style in `.format-$postformat{}` in the stylesheet is not read at all.

Comment: Okay, so do *do* get post-format classes on your posts, right (in your HTML)? But when you try to style them, you aren't seeing your CSS styles? Can you give some example snippets of your HTML and CSS?

Comment: I only see the class in HTML if I override `thematic_post_class`. I've been using the big conditional in `functions.php`, see it here: http://bit.ly/f7WJGq. This recognizes the formats properly but not the CSS classes. Maybe `thematic_post` is the wrong hook? I've tried a few others to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: Trying to figure out the real quesiton here... It sounds like what you want is to be able to use the regular `thematic_post_class` to generate your post classes, but you *also* want to get the appropriate post-format class added to that list as well? Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm going on the assumption that the real question is "how do I get Thematic to add the post-format to its body classes?"

Try this in your functions.php:

```
function my_thematic_post_format_class( $classes = array() ) {
  $format = get_post_format();
  if ( '' == $format )
    $format = 'standard';

  $classes[] = 'format-' . $format;

  return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'post_class', 'my_thematic_post_format_class' );
```

Don't override the thematic post class functions. Just add that filter, and you should be good.

Comment: Excellent!! Works like a charm. Thanks so much. Yea, I think I was making this more complicated than it needed to be...